# NO AUTHENTICATE, when sending request to Office365-Mail-Account

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, office365

i try with PHP (7.4) to authenticate me on my Office365-Mail-Account (Mailbox / IMAP) with an valid Access Token from Microsoft and couldn't find what's missing in the request.

Here you can see, what are my authentification params and what i get back from the request:

[image: Authentification params]

This is the request answer:

[image]

In my error logs i find this:

```
2022/09/22 15:15:37 [error] 485951#485951: *48267 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: got failure response: NO AUTHENTICATE failed" while reading response header from upstream
```

Comment: be sure to use access_token and not id_token.

Comment: @svgta, i'm using the access token.